# list of delegated apps w/ Google SSO

Tags: google-sso

I have a free Google account and I want to get a list of my apps that use delegated Google SSO. For example, I'm using Google SSO with StackOverflow. Is there a way to get a list of such delegations? I know this is possible with Workspace, but I'm asking about the free account.

Answer (score 0):

There are three kinds of apps in your Google Account:

- **Google Workspace apps** (e.g. YouTube)

  - go to “Manage your Google Account”
  - select “Data & privacy tab”
  - scroll down and select “Content saved from Google services”
- **federated apps** (e.g. StackOverflow)

  - go to “Manage your Google Account”
  - select “Data & privacy tab”
  - scroll down and select “Third-party apps with account access”
- **Google Workspace Marketplace apps**

  - https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/myapps